# Is there a spell that can create a permanent fire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, content-identification

I'm looking for a spell which a spell caster would cast to permanently light a torch in their home. Or, maybe a hired arcanist would go around town at sundown to light the street lamps until the morning.

I'm certain I've seen an 'eternal flame' or similar spell around. Unfortunately, my Googling and *Player's Handbook* searching skills seem to be lacking today.

Is there any such spell, or do I need to look into homebrewing some permanent-enchantment rules?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### *Continual Flame*

The spell you are thinking of is called [*continual flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/continual-flame) which is a 2-nd level evocation spell on the Artificer, Cleric, and Wizard spell lists. Each casting costs 50 gp worth of ruby dust and creates a torchlike-flame which lasts indefinitely (until dispelled; notably by *darkness, dispel magic,* or *antimagic field*).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. I guess only fancy cities would spend 50gp on each torch... But it seems to be a one off until the Torch Bearer dies, at least.

Comment: @Shane what do you mean, "until the Torch Bearer dies"? The *Continual Flame* burns forever. Literally. It doesn't matter if its caster dies, the **only** case where it goes out is if it gets dispelled with *Dispel Magic*.

Comment: Important qualifier: this spell only generates light, not heat, so it isn't truly a fire - the name is somewhat misleading. But if OP just wants illumination, then this is the spell.

Comment: I made a remark about the caster dying because I assumed the magic wouldn't continue after they did! I'm not quite sure why I had that in my head though.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent: Darn! I'll just have to stick with the create bonfire cantrip.

Comment: @Joshua or *Fireball*...